# Zeptomail API with attachment

Tags: php, zeptomail

I am unable to properly setup the API request format for Zeptomail API. Below is the sample code -

```
$file = '169242759486.pdf';
$attFile = 'https://www.example.com/secureQCReports/' . $file;
$base64_attFile = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attFile)));

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.zeptomail.in/v1.1/email",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
"from": { "address": "admin@udyog.one", "name": "Ugyod One"},
"to": [{"email_address": {"address": "nkbarman@hotmail.com","name": "Nimesh"}}],
"reply_to": {"address": "sangita143@gmail.com", "name": "Sangita Barman"},
"subject":"Test Email",
"htmlbody":"<div><b> Test email sent successfully. </b></div>",
"attachments": { "content": "$base64_attFile", "mime_type": "application/pdf", "name": "myReport.pdf"},
}',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: application/json",
        "authorization: Zoho-enczapikey **************",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
    ),
));

// "attachments": { "content": "testcontent", "mime_type": "application/pdf", "name": "myinvoice.pdf"},

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

This code returning error  as follows -

> {"error":{"code":"TM_3301","details":[{"code":"SM_101","message":"Invalid value format","target":"zoho-inputstream"}],"message":"Bad Syntax"}}

Anybody kindly help me to get it fixed.

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables, and it's usually a bad idea to write/modify JSON by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me check it

Answer (score 1):

I found the error and fixed it. The actual error was at attachments. it will be a JSON array

**`"attachments": [{ "content": "$base64_attFile", "mime_type": "application/pdf", "name": "myReport.pdf"}],`**